# Conditional formatting based on data in another sheet Excel

Tags: excel

I try to conditional format the table to the right (table2) based on the table to the left (table1) (and the tables are in different sheets):

[image]

All cells corresponding to a cell in table1 with a value different from 0, must be colored in table2, like illustrated below:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want format only corresponding cell just use formula in CF:

```
=Sheet1!B1=1
```

[image]

if you want find proper name then use:

```
=SUM(($A1=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$8)*(1=Sheet1!B$1:B$8))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have a followup question. With startingpoint in your first suggest, I tried to add a condition. Instead of conditional formatting when it's equal to 1, then use conditional formatting when it's different from 0 and "", this was my guess ```=AND(Sheet1!B1<>0,Sheet1!B1<>"")```, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @User123456789 It should work. Check if ```Applies to``` range matches the formula range. Remember that you write formula for the first upper cell of the appliesto range. For the other cells, the relative cells of the formula changes accordingly.